# Auto delete captcha image CI

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I'm using captcha helper from CodeIgniter to generate Captcha image for registration user. I've some value like this:

```
$vals = array(
        'word' => $rand_word,
        'img_path' => 'resources/captcha/',
        'img_url' => 'http://localhost/fitinline/resources/captcha/',
        'font_path' => './path/to/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width' => 150,
        'img_height' => 40,
        'expiration' => 7200
    );
```

The captcha image automatically saved to 'img_path' when I generate captcha using `create_captcha($vals)` function. There is expiration index that I set default to 2 hours (7200). But after more than two hours, I check the image in 'img_path', the image are still saved on it. Is there any missing configuration to enable automatically delete those captcha image or what,.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on CI Documentation:

```
$vals = array(
    'word'   => 'Random word',
    'img_path'   => './captcha/',
    'img_url'    => 'http://example.com/captcha/',
    'font_path'  => './path/to/fonts/texb.ttf',
    'img_width'  => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 7200
    );
```

*The "expiration" (in seconds) signifies how long an image will remain in the captcha folder before it will be deleted. The default is two hours.*

Answer (score 4):

without cron, there is no way that images would delete themselves after their expiration time.
But, when someone will trigger captcha helper, he will check if there is any image that shouldn't be there and he delete them.

Let say you have got captcha in registration. I'm creating new account. New captcha is also created with 7200 time of expiration. You open your folder with images of captcha after more than 7200 and the pictures are still there. The next day someone else is creating new account, new captcha is created. But in that moment helper see that there is image that should not be there (from yesterday) and he deletes it.

So you should not be worry, that there are images in captcha folder. They should be deleted as soon as some new captcha is created and their time expired. You can check in captcha_helper file there is part of code for:

```
    // -----------------------------------
    // Remove old images
    // -----------------------------------
```

If you can't waint until helper is trigger, you should create script for removing images and add it to cron.

Answer (score 1):

is the captcha working properly ? ( have you checked  directory permissions ? )

I am not sure about this, but try saving results of `create_captcha()` the database as mentioned in CI Guide.

```
CREATE TABLE captcha (
 captcha_id bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 captcha_time int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 ip_address varchar(16) default '0' NOT NULL,
 word varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY `captcha_id` (`captcha_id`),
 KEY `word` (`word`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Add script to delete all captcha file*/

$files = glob('./captcha/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file)
{ 
  // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```